# Determine Datatype using Regexp

Tags: php, sql, regex

I have a string. I should generate a sql text. Can I determine datatype using regexp.
For examle : 15.04.2013 or 2013/04/15 or 15/04/2013 is date. 
             15 , 46 is integer / int
             1 or 0 is boolean ... etc.

Comment: Why use regex? [`gettype`](http://php.net/gettype) works perfectly for bool, int, string, object, array, etc... Then if its a string you can proceed to check the date / other custom formats you'd like.

Comment: Because data came as "15.04.2013" if I use gettype it returns "string" always.

Comment: Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Not only date data. There are float, integer, current format in text.

Comment: @ziyahan In what format is the date ?

Comment: First you have to test them... For instance, $i == (string)intval($i) then it is integer etc... parseFloat etc can be helpfull. I assume they are all incoming as strings...

Comment: `1` or `0` are not boolean! `true` and `false` are boolean, but casting `1` or `0` to boolean will return the expected result

Answer (score 2):

Using [gettype()](http://php.net/gettype) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), the following function checks whether it's boolean, integer, float or date:

```
function get_type($input){
    $type = gettype($input);
    if($type == 'string'){
        if(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false){
            return 'integer';
        }elseif(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) !== false){
            return 'float';
        }elseif(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) !== false){
            return 'boolean';
        }elseif(strtotime($input) !== false){
            return 'date';
        }
    }elseif($type == 'double'){
        return 'float';
    }
    return $type;
}
```

**Input:**

```
echo '0 : <b>'.get_type(0).'</b><br>';
echo '1 : <b>'.get_type(1).'</b><br>';
echo '1.11 : <b>'.get_type(1.11).'</b><br>';
echo '1.2e3 : <b>'.get_type(1.2e3).'</b><br>';
echo 'true : <b>'.get_type(true).'</b><br>';
echo 'false : <b>'.get_type(false).'</b><br>';
echo '\'wut\' : <b>'.get_type('wut').'</b><br>';
echo 'array() : <b>'.get_type(array()).'</b><br>';
echo '\'TRUE\' : <b>'.get_type('TRUE').'</b><br>';
echo '\'false\' : <b>'.get_type('TRUE').'</b><br>';
echo '\'0\' : <b>'.get_type('0').'</b><br>';
echo '\'1\' : <b>'.get_type('1').'</b><br>';
echo '\'15.04.2013\' : <b>'.get_type('15.04.2013').'</b><br>';
echo '\'15 april 2013\' : <b>'.get_type('15 april 2013').'</b><br>';
echo '\'+7 days\' : <b>'.get_type('+7 days').'</b><br>'; // fail in a way
echo '\'15/04/2013\' : <b>'.get_type('15/04/2013').'</b><br>'; // fail
echo '\'25-10-2013 wut\' : <b>'.get_type('25-10-2013 wut').'</b><br>';
echo '\'500\' : <b>'.get_type('500').'</b><br>';
echo '\'54.360\' : <b>'.get_type('54.360').'</b><br>';
echo '\'+54.360\' : <b>'.get_type('+54.360').'</b><br>';
echo '\'1.2e3\' : <b>'.get_type('1.2e3').'</b><br>';
echo '\'7E-10\' : <b>'.get_type('7E-10').'</b><br>';
```

**Output:**

```
0 : integer
1 : integer
1.11 : float
1.2e3 : float
true : boolean
false : boolean
'wut' : string
array() : array
'TRUE' : boolean
'false' : boolean
'0' : integer
'1' : integer
'15.04.2013' : date
'15 april 2013' : date
'+7 days' : date
'15/04/2013' : string
'25-10-2013 wut' : string
'500' : integer
'54.360' : float
'+54.360' : float
'1.2e3' : float
'7E-10' : float
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and stupid checker... But I have to mention that you can not be sure about date and month...(for days < 13)...

```
 $s = '01/04/2013';

 if (($s=='0') || ($s=='1') || ($s=='true') || ($s=='false')) return('boolean');

 if ((string)intval($s) == $s) return('integer');

 if (intval($s).'TL' == $s) return('currency');

 if ((string)parseFloat($s) == $s) return('float');

 $a = explode('.', $s);
 if (count($a) != 3) $a = explode('/', $s);
 if (count($a) != 3) return('I do not know');
```

Here you have to fill in checking for each member of `$a` ...

`$a[0]`, `$a[1]`, and `$a[2]` are supposed to contain date elements, so you check them...

Beware, month may be a text like "Nisan","Mayıs","Haziran"

If they are valid return :

```
 return('date');
```