# Set a variable on regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Is possible to declare a variable to regular expression? For example, I have an expression that matches two types of data, and I would like to define a variable that informs the matched type.

```
~ ( \d+ | \w+ ) ~x
```

It'll match digits or characters. I would like to store an information of the type of matched data (manually). For instance:

```
~ ( (?<type>"int") \d+ | <?<type>"string"> \w+ ) ~x
```

So result will be:

```
"123" -> { 0: "123", "type": "int",    1: "123" }
"ABC" -> { 0: "ABC", "type": "string", 1: "ABC" }
```

The closest solution I got was to define a group that covers this type of information, and name it in a specific way.

```
~ ( (?<type_int> \d+) | (?<type_string> \w+) ) ~x
```

In this case the result is:

```
"123" -> { 0: "123", "type_int": "123" }
"ABC" -> { 0: "ABC", "type_string": "ABC" }
```

Comment: I think the solution you came up with is the best way of doing this.

Comment: You may loop through the array and use the following function I wrote in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16017548)

Comment: @HamZa thanks, but the example I was given was only for understanding. The type of information is not necessarily the type of subject data. It could be an "email" type, for example.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues Well then, I think your solution using named groups is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are not designed to solve these problems, but a solution is possible, although this is a "hack":

```
$text= "some text 1234";
$regex= <<< THISISREGEX
/
(
    (\\d++) |
    \\w++
)
(?=.*
    (?P<type>
        (?(2)int|string)
    )
)
(?!
    .{,9}\$(?<=intstring)
)
/xs
THISISREGEX;
preg_match_all($regex, $text."intstring", $arr);
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr[0]); $i++) {
    echo $arr[1][$i]."\t\t".$arr["type"][$i]."\n";
};
```

Output:

```
some        string
text        string
1234        int
```

[IDEone example](http://ideone.com/OKySZA)

Comment: Another "dirty" solution, proving that you should not use regular expressions for such tasks [IDEone](http://ideone.com/niNAv4)

Comment: Despite being a hack, it was worth the effort. It was exactly what I expected. I will continue to use my own method, but if you said exactly what my question asked, you deserve to take credit. Only an additional: Could you briefly explain this regular expression?